# Android Camera Image Name

Tags: android, image, camera, storage

I'm trying to build a simple application which captures images. I had successfully implemented the application till Android M. I faced the FileUriExposedException on Android N but then I could solve it with the help of this [link](https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker/issues/9) which suggested this code 
`

```
capture_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(camera_intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg");
                    fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
                    camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
                    camera_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
                                           Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Visitor_Details.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

`

This piece of code stores the Image in Pictures Folder with a random 13 digit integer as its image name eg:- 1507922385727.jpg. I tried reading the fileUri via Log.d() but the value returned by the Log and the Image name were not same. How is this image name being generated? How do I store this image name so that I can pass this via a intent to display the image in the next Activity? Lastly, how do I create a sub folder inside the Pictures where I could direct these images?
PS :- Previously, I was using SimpleDateFormat to get a TimeStamp as my Image Name and I created the Folder using File class.The getImageName() just returns the timestamp value. Here's the code I used for previous version of Android. 
`

```
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File imageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Camera Test");
                String imageName = getImageName();
                File imagePath = new File(imageDir,imageName);
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
                camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(camIntent,1);

            }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this image name being generated?

That is up to the `MediaStore`. Use your original code, but use `FileProvider` to serve up access to the file location and get your `Uri`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/FileProvider) for how to use `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Thanks. Camera works. Except now, I'm getting IllegalArgumentException.